# Filter collection that references to itself

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-runtime

Lets say I have an `ObservableCollection` filled with records from an entity.
The entity contains integer fields as they go `knr`:`lnr`:`sknr`.
Each `knr` can have multiple `lnr` so that means. So this means the they are children of `knr`.
Each `lnr` can be parent of multiple `sbknr`.

So the relation goes  1:n:m (`knr`) : (`lnr`) : (`sbkr`)

I see in the table that there are records which match each other but I`m having issues getting the via LINQ.

I though a simple `Where` method from `System.Linq` with do the job, unfortunately not

```
var filteredRecords = LanrChildrenOfKnr
    .Where(la => ((kunden)la.Entity).knr == 
        ((kunden)((VUEntityWrapper)WorkAliasCollection.Source).Entity).lnr);
```

Any solutions would be great!

Comment: Could you post your entities here? What are the Foregign Key Columns you use for your relation?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE [kunden] (
  [knr] integer(10) NOT NULL ON CONFLICT IGNORE, 
  [lanr] integer(10) NOT NULL ON CONFLICT IGNORE, 
  [sbknr] integer(4) NOT NULL ON CONFLICT IGNORE, 
  [typ] C(15) NOT NULL ON CONFLICT IGNORE, 
  [name] C(64) NOT NULL ON CONFLICT IGNORE, 
  [adresse1] C(64), 
  [adresse2] C(64), 
  [adresse3] C(64), 
  [plzort] C(64), 
  [telefon] C(64), 
  [handy] C(64), 
  [email] C(64), 
  [neu] BOOLEAN, 
  [loeschen] BOOLEAN, 
  [geaendert] BOOLEAN, 
  [kundenid] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT);`

Comment: The entity has references to itself because there are different types of address (lnr, knr, sbknr)

Comment: Isn't this just something you want to fix with Grouping? or with a ToLookUp() extension method?

Comment: a first observation is that you are comparing the knr and lnr properties of your entities. Shouldn't you be searching on the same column?

Comment: I need to get all of the records which knr match for lanr!

Comment: Can you post the foreign key definition here? From the database. I want to make sure that you got the column names right.

Comment: My friend there are no foreign keys just this entity, All I want is to filter the records. KNR can contains many LANR I want to get all of the records which knr == lanr for the table kunden.

Comment: ToLookUp has done the job! Thanks verry much Jordy van Eijk!